# emmeans doesn't show the correct output

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, p-value, multiple-comparisons, lsmeans

I am running the following LMER model with **Place** (five dummy-coded levels: bilabial, dental, retroflex, palatal, and velar) and **Laryngeal** (three dummy-coded levels: voiceless unaspirated, voiceless aspirated, and voiced unaspirated) as fixed factors, **Speaker** as a random factor.

```
lmer_model <- lmer(VOT ~ Place+Laryngeal + (1+Place+Laryngeal|Speaker), data = data)

summary(lmer_model)
```

Then I use `emmeans()` to look at the pairwise comparisons.

```
emmeans(lmer_model, pairwise~Laryngeal|Place, lmer.df = "satterthwaite")
```

The output of emmeans can be found below.

If you look at the p values and estimates, they all look similar. I am not sure what may be wrong.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results you see are consistent with the model that you built.

Your model includes only additive terms for `Place` and `Laryngeal`, without any interactions. That makes an assumption that the effect of *differences* among `Laryngeal` categories will be the same regardless of `Place`.

The absolute values of `VOT` might well differ from `Place` to `Place`, which you could examine with a different call to `emmeans()`. But the pairwise comparisons you show are between pairs of `Laryngeal` categories within the same `Place`, so those *differences* should be the same for each `Place`, as you found.

If you expect the influence of `Laryngeal` categories to have different effects on `VOT` depending on `Place`, then you need to include an interaction term between those predictors. You will need a pretty large study to evaluate that possibility, as with 5 levels of `Place` and 3 of `Laryngeal` the interactions between them will add 8 more fixed predictors to your model. You also will need to evaluate whether you need to incorporate more random effects for interactions.

Comment: Thanks EdM for the suggestion. Now I realized what was wrong with the model. I added an interaction term and it works well.